# Running a console command which is stored in `std::wstring`

Tags: c++, unicode, command-line, console, wstring

I have a console command, something like:

```
std::wstring ConsoleCommand;
ConsoleCommand = L"c:\\somepath\\anotherpath\\program.exe -opt1 /opt2 --opt3";
```

I want to execute this command.
How do I do it?

(It may be a Win32 API function, or a standard C/C++ library.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try [ShellExecute()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb762153%28v=vs.85%29.aspx). You probably want the **open** verb. You could also use [CreateProcess()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms682425%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

Comment: `ShellExecute` has explicit versions `ShellExecuteA` and `ShellExecuteW`, the undecorated version takes the situational `TCHAR`-string argument.

Comment: Not sure how that's relevant. Nearly all WinAPIs that deal with strings/chars in any way have ANSI and Unicode versions.

Comment: It's just a comment to help the OP find a way to solve her problem. She didn't specify any project settings, so I figured adding some info couldn't hurt...

Answer (score 3):

You *must* [_wsystem()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/277bwbdz.aspx) or [_wpopen()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/96ayss4b%28v=vs.71%29.aspx) on Windows.

Comment: [`_wsystem`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/277bwbdz.aspx) is the wide corollary to `system`.